# How to show that $T(B)=AB$ is orthonormal diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, orthonormal

Consider $V = \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ as an inner product space with respect to the dot product. Let $A\in V$ be a  diagonalize orthonormal matrix. Show that the linear operator $T : V \to V$ defined by $T(B)=AB$  is orthonormal diagonalizable.

We were told a hint that we can show that if $v \in \mathbb C^{n \times 1}$ is an eigenvector of $A,$  we can conclude that for a matrix $B$ such that $v$ is the column and the rest are zeroes, there exists $T(B)=\lambda B.$

I concluded that, but how do I proceed from here?

Comment: basically the hint answers your question. Try to produce $n^2$ eigenvectors for $T$ from the $n$ eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: what will I earn if I will produce that? how is that can help me?

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Comment: Observe that $T$ is a linear operator on the $n^2$-dimensional vector space of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb C.$ One shows that $T$ is diagonalizable by providing a basis of ($n^2$ in this case) eigenvectors for $T.$

Comment: @Sagigever. The system here works like this: If the answer answers your question, then you should accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each eigenvector $v_i$ of $A$, you can form $n$ eigenvector $B_{i,1},\ldots,B_{i,n}$ of $T$ as follows:

$$B_{i,1}=(v_i\, 0\,\cdots 0),\; B_{i,2}=(0\,v_i\,\cdots\,0)\cdots B_{i,n}=(0\,\cdots\,0\,v_i).$$
Note that we have written $v_i$ and $0$ in the column form, so the $B_{i,j}$ are $n\times n$ matrices. Moreover, if $Av_i=\lambda v_i$ then $TB_{i,j}=\lambda B_{i,j}$ for all $j=1,\ldots,n$.

Now let $i$ vary from $1$ to $n$, to get $n^2$ eigenvectors of $T$, namely the $B_{i,j}$'s for $i,j=1,\ldots,n$.

Next, you need to check that the $B_{i,j}$'s are linearly independent. This is not difficult, and follows from the linear independence of the $v_i$'s. Since $\dim V=n^2$, it tells you that $T$ is diagonalizable.

For the orthonormality, we have $\left\langle B_{i,j},B_{k,\ell}\right\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(B_{i,j}B_{k,\ell}^{T})=\delta_{i,k}\delta_{j,\ell}$. So the set of $B_{i,j}$ is orthonormal.