# Let $T(B)=AB$ be any linear operator where $A$ is fixed. Then if $A$ is diagonalizable then $T$ is also diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Let $V$ be the space of $n\times n$ matrices over a field $F$. Let $A$ be a fixed matrix in $V$. Let $T$ and be linear operators on $V$ defined by
>
> $T(B)=AB$

I was trying to approach it in a way so that we don't have to use minimal polynomial.

To show that $T$ is diagonalizable we need to show that there exists $n^2$ distinct matrices $\{B_{11},\cdots B_{nn} \}$ such that $T(B_{ij}) = \lambda_j B_{ij}$ .

We see that $A$ is diagonalizable means there exists $n$ distinct vectors $\{v_1,\cdots , v_n\}$ such that $T(v_i) = c_j.v_i$.

Let $\{e_1,\cdots e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$ then I was trying to construct $B_{ij}$ as $B_{ij}(e_i) = v_j$ and $0$ otherwise (for all $1 \le i \le n$).

Then $T(B_{ij}) = AB_{ij}$ .

Now $A.B_{ij}(e_i) = A(e_i) = c_k.v_j = c_k.B_{ij}(e_j)$ .

Then $T(B_{ij})= c_k.B_{ij}$.

Can someone help me out with this approach?

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3716850/942722).

Comment: So i guess my work is correct?

Comment: As it was in the link, you need to show that $B_{ij}$ are linear independent.